# View does not update without zoom gesture

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI. But i got stuck and i don't know why.

My `ContentView` is combined out of 3 views: `DrawPlayer`, `DrawNextPoints`, `Gameboard`. `Player` is a class not a struct. I have defined it as an `ObservableObject`, because i will change its properties. With my `DrawNextPoint` i draw a circle and add an `.onTabGesture`. All of this works, but i have to make use of the `MagnificationGesture` so my ContentView gets an update and displays the clicked circles.
If i don‘t zoom, nothing updates.

Thanks for your help.

Here is my ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
        
    @StateObject var player1 = Player(actualPoint: Gameboard().startPoint1, color: .red)
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView ([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Gameboard()
                }
                var _ = print(player1.actualPoint)
                var _ = print(player1.movePoints)
                ForEach(player1.actualPoint, id:\.self) { actualPoint in
                    DrawNextPoints(player: player1)
                }
                
                ForEach(player1.movePoints, id:\.self) { movePoints in
                    DrawPlayer(player: player1)
                }
                
            }
            .position(CGPoint(x:1000, y:1000))
            .scaleEffect(scale)
            .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
                .onChanged { scale in
                    self.scale = scale.magnitude
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

And my Player class:

```
import SwiftUI

class Player: ObservableObject {
    
    private var _speedX: Double = 0.0
    private var _speedY: Double = 1.0
    var _actualPoint: Array<Double>
    var _movePoints: Array<Array<Double>>
    private var _color: SwiftUI.Color
    
    public init(actualPoint: Array<Double>, color: SwiftUI.Color) {
        self._actualPoint = actualPoint
        self._color = color
        self._movePoints = [actualPoint]
    }
    
    public var speedX:Double {
        get{
            return _speedX
        }
        set{
            _speedX = newValue
        }
    }
    
    public var speedY:Double {
        get{
            return self._speedY
        }
        set{
            self._speedY = newValue
        }
    }
    
    public var actualPoint: Array<Double> {
        get{
            return self._actualPoint
        }
        set{
            self._actualPoint = newValue
        }
        
    }
    
    public var movePoints: Array<Array<Double>> {
        get{
            return self._movePoints
        }
        set{
            self._movePoints = newValue
        }
    }
    
    public var color: SwiftUI.Color {
        get{
            return self._color
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please show also your Player class

Comment: i edit my question and add the player class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `ObservableObject` class `Player`, you need to use the `@Published` property wrapper: it notifies the views that the observed object will change.

In your class do this:

```
class Player: ObservableObject {
    
    private var _speedX: Double = 0.0
    private var _speedY: Double = 1.0
    @Published var _actualPoint: Array<Double>
    @Published var _movePoints: Array<Array<Double>>
    private var _color: SwiftUI.Color

// …

}
```